# How many moras in [steak]? I produced two moras.

Tags: phonology, linguistic-typology

I drew the syllable structure for steak, and I deduced that 'st' is one cluster and forms part of the onset instead of the rhyme. So that leaves the rhyme with eI and k which will give me two moras. Is this correct?

Comment: Are you sure that English has moras? Latin did, for sure, and Japanese does. _Mora_ is a theoretical term describing a phenomenon that may not be present or relevant in all languages. Theories can be revised to use or not to use a mora analysis of syllable structure.

Answer (score 2):

A rather different perspective of the analysis of [the ***st-*** cluster in English](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/style.pdf)
(though it does not, alas, mention moras).

I would guess from the evidence that *st-* has been perceptually clustered for quite a while,
and isn't perceived as two units by native speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Most text books focus on single consonant onsets (called simplex onsets) so dealing with a complex onset like /st/ can be confusing.

If you take a look at section 2 in [this overview of moraic theory](http://www.uni-leipzig.de/~topintzi/papers/companion_onsets.pdf), you can see that complex onsets do it in one of two ways: the either treat the complex onset as two separate consonants or they say that the features of the consonants linearize, for lack of a better word, and effectively turn into a single consonant. Either way the result seems to be that a complex onset does not take significantly more time than a simplex onset and thus does need any extra moras.

However, You should also be aware of *superheavy syllables*, defined in the Wikipedia article for [syllable weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable_weight). These are syllables with two V segments (a long vowel or a diphthong) plus a coda or a single V and two C segments in the coda for a total of three moras per syllable. Superheavy syllables don't appear in every language but I believe they do in English. So the question is whether the vowel in "steak" is a diphthong. For me it isn't but you seem to think it is.